# Require and Include Fails to Find and Open file PHP 5.5.5

Tags: nginx, php

Running PHP 5.5.5 FPM/FastCGI on CentOS 6.4 x64 with Nginx.

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/adminsetting.php') or die();
```

returns the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '1'
(include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
/home/vincek/public_html/plg/index.php on line 4
```

The file `adminsetting.php` is located in the same dir as `index.php` and exists.

I've double checked everything I can think of, php is running under the current user, all the ownership and permissions are correct.

I can't figure out why this file cannot be found.

Do I need a separate location block in my vhost.conf for this directory?

--EDIT--
Additional code was requested:

from index.php:

```
session_start();
$base_path=substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] , 0 , -strlen($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])+0).dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/adminsetting.php');
setcookie("usercheck", " ", time()-60*5);
include($require_path."/functions.php");
if($datastoreselected=="2")include_once($mysql_path."/connection.php");
include("header.php");
include("side.php");
... etc ...
```

From adminsetting.php:

```
$root_path="/home/vincek/public_html/plg";
$base_path="/home/vincek/public_html/plg";
$adminurl="http://vincek.co";
$admininstalldirectory="/plg";
$base_url="http://vincek.co/plg/";
$site_title="Power Link Generator v4.8";
$require_path="/home/vincek/public_html/plg/include";
$template_path="/home/vincek/public_html/plg/templates";
$mysql_path="/home/vincek/public_html/plg/mysql";
$image_path="http://vincek.co/plg/images";
$adminbase="/home/vincek/public_html/";
... etc ...
```

IF the `adminsetting` file is being included ... why would the called variables not be found?

Comment: are you able to just call the file as such `require_once "adminsetting.php";`? Also try seeing what the output of that directory is with `scandir('dir_path');`. Might give you some insight into what the problem is.

Comment: no it won't load with just the filename either, that's why I added in the absolute path, which I did check first to make sure it was the correct path.  I'll try a scan_dir and see what that shows.

Comment: What happens if you put in the absolute path, i.e. `require_once('/home/vincek/public_html/plg/adminsetting.php');`?

Comment: scandir DOES show the file listed in the array.

Comment: Same error when using the pull path as a string.

Comment: Dumb question possibly but is your adminsetting.php variables in a class? I am assuming not but I have to ask.

Comment: No not in a class.  I should rewrite that whole script, but for now I just need to get it working.

Comment: require_once shouldn't be affected by any settings in the web server, as it happens entirely within PHP. The problem is presumably some detail of that included file. Did you try adding some output to it to see what is being executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Require does not return a value, so it will always die at your `or die()`.
Use

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/adminsetting.php');
```

If it fails, it will cause a fatal error anyway. That's what require does: it includes a script, or dies on failure

EDIT:

Your adminsetting file is being interpreted as text and I can't understand why. It may have some character that is messing with you `<?` code blocks. I've seen it happen with XML files having a null character (after some wiseguy edited the XML file with Word, and waited for my parser to do the rest). My best suggestion for now is to move the adminsetting file somewhere else, create a new adminsetting file, write the php code blocks yourself and just copy the rest of the code in the new file. The problem has to be the adminsetting file, nothing else.

Comment: Right, I added the die to get it to print out a value. It's not loading the file because none of the variables in that file are found in the subsequent scripting, yet, it's not throwing any errors about not loading.  Is there any other reason that my variables would be not found OTHER than the file not being included?

Comment: `require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/adminsetting.php');` produces all the erors found on this page here: http://vincek.co/plg/

Comment: If the file was not included, then it would produce a fatal error. Something else is happening here. To check if your adminsetting.php is included, make it print something for debugging. I suppose if you post some of your code, you might get some extra help.

Comment: Ok I'll adjust my answer and add some additional code.  Keep in mind it's not MY code, and older script I use for tracking links. But this script works fine on my Apache server.  I really feel this is something with the set up of the server blocks.  I have a Wordpress site up on this server and it works great.

Comment: The `require_once` works, but I believe that the code of adminsetting.php is interpreted as plain text, thus never executed.

Comment: Ah, now we're getting somewhere.  That makes more sense. So, the error is in the server block then somewhere.  For some reason all the php files aren't being passed up to the interpreter.  Hmmm .....

Comment: I've edited my answer with another thought. Note that I did see your adminsetting source code, so please take appropriate care if security is an issue for you

Answer (score 3):

The trap is that `require_once` is a statement, not a function, so the brackets around the filename are misleading. What actually runs is the same as `require_once ('something.php' or die);` which becomes `require_once true;` and thence `require_once '1';`, which explains the error message.

As others have pointed out, `require_once` will die on its own anyway, but if you did want to use `include_once` with this idiom, you need to arrange the brackets differently: `(include_once 'something.php') or die;`

Comment: Yeah that's not the issue though, the issue is that file isn't being included.  None of the variables in the settings file are able to be found, thus it's not being included properly. See: http://vincek.co/plg/

Comment: Well, it's the issue with the code you posted, because it is trying to load the file '1',  which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
<?
```

to

```
<?php
```

in your included file.

`<?` can't be used in the latest php releases (if you do not make configuration changes).